# TensorFlow: Implementing Single layer perceptron / Multi layer perceptron using own data set

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, perceptron, tensorflow-datasets

I am new to **TensorFlow.** I looked for examples on  implementation of multi layer perceptron using tensorflow, but i am  getting **examples only on MNIST image** **data sets**, apart from MNIST can i able to build the Neural Network model using same optimization and cost functions and train the data which is in number format,**Means, Can I train my own number dataset using tensorflow.**

**Is there any example for training the new dataset?**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally i got it. Building , Training and minimizing cost / loss of an Artificial Neural Network using Single Layer Perceptron with tensorflow, numpy , matplotlib packages. **Data is used in the form of array instead** of MNIST. 
Here is the code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
learning_rate = 0.0008
training_epochs = 2000
display_step = 50
# taking input as array from numpy package and converting it into tensor
inputX = np.array([[  2,   3],
                  [  1,   3]])
inputY = np.array([[  2,   3],
                  [  1,   3]])
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])

W = tf.Variable([[0.0,0.0],[0.0,0.0]])
b = tf.Variable([0.0,0.0])

layer1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, W), b)
y = tf.nn.softmax(layer1)

cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(y_-y,2))

optimizer =tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

avg_set = []
epoch_set = []

for i in range(training_epochs):
   sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict = {x: inputX, y_:inputY})

   #log training
   if i % display_step == 0:
       cc = sess.run(cost, feed_dict = {x: inputX, y_:inputY})
       #check what it thinks when you give it the input data
       print(sess.run(y, feed_dict = {x:inputX}))


       print("Training step:", '%04d' % (i), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(cc))
       avg_set.append(cc)
       epoch_set.append(i + 1)

print("Optimization Finished!")
training_cost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict = {x: inputX, y_: inputY})
print("Training cost = ", training_cost, "\nW=", sess.run(W),
      "\nb=", sess.run(b))
plt.plot(epoch_set,avg_set,'o',label = 'SLP Training phase')
plt.ylabel('cost')
plt.xlabel('epochs')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Later by adding hidden layers it can be also implemented with Multi Layer Perceptron

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the TensorFlow [multilayer perceptron example](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/exaYoumples/3_NeuralNetworks/multilayer_perceptron.py) is easy. You will need to specify your input and output size here

```
n_input = # Input size (MNIST uses 28*28 size images = 784 pixels)
n_classes = # Output size (MNIST classifies into 0-9 digits)
```

Finally, you have to change the training cycle code to work with your dataset. I cannot help you more as I don't know anything about your dataset.

Comment: Link :  https://drive.google.com/open?id=13UOhg6KcUXc4T2JGMfEKueX3gubYQw0n                                 Here is my code My cost function is zero from first epoch itself, not getting exactly were the error is. please help me out. And the multi layer link you given above is showing error.                                                                Thanks in advance